# converting old iphone applications (ios2.2.1) to newer iphone applications (ios4)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, bonjour

Bill Dudney created a [sample iPhone Bonjour application](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/resource/NetworkingTesting.zip) to demonstrate how to use Bonjour to discover and connect to two iPhones. Unfortunately, this application was made for ios2.2.1. Does anyone know how to convert this application to the new ios4? OR if someone knows of another example application that is made for ios4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't run (errors out) on an iOS 4 device then you need access the source code and build it from Xcode with the iOS 4 SDK. From there you will need to fix any sort of warnings or errors which happen at compile time. Then you should be able to deploy it just fine.

If you have no idea how to do this, try and get in touch with me and I will see about converting it for you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind giving me an email at drummerboyx(at)verizon(dot)net ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the Documentation ("Initializing and Publishing a Network Service"):
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html

and the associated sample project at:
/Developer/Examples/Foundation/PictureSharing

Aren't what you're looking for?